# Stand-alone text editor with Visual Studio editor functionality

Tags: editor, text-editor

Is anyone aware of any text editors with Visual Studio editor functionality? Specifically, I'm looking for the following features:

CTRL+C anywhere on the line, no text selected -> the whole line is copied

CTRL+X or SHIFT+DEL anywhere on the line, no text selected -> the whole line cut
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/Products/komodo_ide/komodo_edit.mhtml) does the two things you specified.

I use it all the time as a secondary editor, for various scripting and other programming tasks. Tons of features, free, open source.

Comment: +1 Open Source is always a good option when you have no budget!

Answer (score 3):

[Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) can emulate the Visual Studio keyboard.

To change the keyboard mapping just use the **Options**, **Editor Option** menu and in the **Keyboard** panel and select the MSVC as the active keyboard mapping.

[image]
<sub>(source: [zeusedit.com](http://www.zeusedit.com/images/_lookmain.jpg))</sub>

Comment: The cost of a single user license is: $USD 69.95

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++, UltraEdit and TextPad are good ones.

Answer (score 1):

[EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com/) will cut or copy the line the cursor is on when no text is selected.  People sometimes report that as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

[Twistpad](http://www.carthagosoft.net/twistpad/index.htm) looks something like Visual Studio 2005/2008 editor and seems has the same key bindings, including Ctrl-X to cut whole line if no text was marked.

Answer (score 0):

[Slickedit](http://www.slickedit.com/)

Comment: SlickEdit 2009 for Windows   $299.00 
Not Cheap!

Answer (score 0):

Not to steal Chris' thunder for his suggestions on Notepad++, UltraEdit, and TextPad, but I would like to point out that there is a version of [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ue3.html) which can be run from a thumb drive (for those people who lack Admin rights at work and can not install programs).

Comment: +1 Looks like another responder downvoted all of our answers.  #lame