# How to mimic Visual Studio's CTRL-X, CTRL-V functionality in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ for some projects and miss Visual Studio's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> functionality that cuts or copies the entire current line when no text is selected.  The cut line shortcut seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, which is not as convenient as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and the copy shortcut seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, which is even less convenient.

Although a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128625/stand-alone-text-editor-with-visual-studio-editor-functionality) has been asked before, the way to do this in Notepad++ was not provided and I cannot find a solution on the Notepad++ site or on its forums.

Answer (score 27):

I've created a Notepad++ plugin that does this (without the need of python).  An archived version of it can be found at https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/projects/za/zastrowm/notepad-visualstudiolinecopy.html.

Comment: This should be the Accepted Answer. The plugin works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: It looks like this plugin is 32-bit only, so It doesn't work with 64-bit Notepad++ :-(

Comment: I understand this is old but it now says repository no longer available - FYI

Comment: Look like it was a mercurial repo which Bitbucket eventually removed support for.  Archives seem to be up at https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/projects/za/zastrowm/notepad-visualstudiolinecopy.html

Answer (score 21):

Synthesizing all other answers and comments, plus some additional necessary steps that haven't been mentioned:

Scintilla provides a "copyAllowLine" command that does this.  Notepad++ doesn't expose that command in the shortcut mapper, but you can call it from a Python script and map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to that script.  There is no corresponding command for "cutAllowLine", but a bit of extra Python code will do it.  These scripts must be added to the menu and Notepad++ must restart before they will become available in the shortcut mapper.

1. Install [Python Script](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) plugin(can be done with Notepad++ Plugin Manager)
2. Create the following two python scripts using the menu Plugins -> Python Script -> New script

   #### copyAllowLine.py

   ```
   editor.copyAllowLine()
   ```

   #### cutAllowLine.py

   ```
   if editor.getSelectionStart() == editor.getSelectionEnd():
       editor.lineCut()
   else:
       editor.cut()
   ```
3. Python Script -> Configuration

   - under **User Scripts**, add a menu item for each script.
4. Restart notepad++ (important)
5. Settings -> Shortcut Mapper...

   - under **Scintilla Commands**, remove the existing associations for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
   - under **Plugin commands**, find the scripts you just created and map your shortcuts to them.

Note: when installed via plugin manager, version 1.0.6 was installed. When I attempted to run anything python related in Notepad++ I got an unknown exception from plugin manager. The solution was to manually download and install the 1.0.8 .msi from here: [1.0.8 installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%201.0.8.0/)

Comment: I couldn't find NppPython in the plugin manager. I installed from its website without problems, but after install it was listed as "Python Script". Perhaps it's listed as that under Available Plugins as well now. Other than that minor wrinkle, these instructions still work just fine. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, if you subsequently want Ctrl-V to paste what you just copy / cut, then add the Ctrl-V binding under the scintilla commands to the SCI_PASTE command.  Without doing this I was seeing CTRL for the paste contents.

Comment: Note that the Python Script plugin only is available for the 32-bit version and doesn't show up in plugin manager for 64 bit versions. Installing it manually won't work either.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install [NppPython plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) (can be done with Notepad++ Plugin Manager)
2. Create this python script using the menu Plugins -> Python Script -> New script:

   ```
   if editor.getSelectionStart() == editor.getSelectionEnd():
       editor.lineCut()
   else:
       editor.cut()
   ```
3. Restart notepad++ (important)
4. Go to Menu Settings -> Shortcut Mapper -> Plugin commands
5. Find the script you just created in the list and set CTRL+X shortcut for it
6. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings->Shortcut Mapper and click on the "Scintilla commands" tab at the top.  Under there you should be able to change the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> command to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work.  Maybe it cannot overload the two maps for CTRL-X. Do you have to remap CTRL-X as well?

Comment: I just tried it with removing CTRL-X from the CUT command and adding it to only the CUT LINE command, give that a try.

Comment: Thanks again, but then what happens is that the CTRL-X will delete the entire line, even if text is selected.  These are seemingly small differences but when you do the operation hundreds of times a session it adds up.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I can't find a way to mimic this functionality exactly with just using the options. Sorry :(

Comment: Well, I appreciate your assistance and for pointing out the Scintilla commands.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a script with the Python Script Notepad++ plugin, and assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to the script (remove the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> mapping from SCI_COPY in shortcut mapper, Scintilla Commands tab)

The script is just:

```
if editor.getSelectionStart() == editor.getSelectionEnd():
    line = editor.getCurLine()
    editor.copyText(line)
else:
    editor.copy()
```

Obviously just add another similar script for Ctrl-X that removes the line instead.

Comment: It's just been pointed out that Scintilla supports it directly, so you can use editor.copyAllowLine()

Comment: Dave - Can you expand on what you mean there? I want to implement this script but I'm not sure where your comment applies.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now I've played with it! Is there a reason why that Scintilla command doesn't appear in the Scintilla Commands in Notepad++ itself? Shame that there doesn't seem to be a cutAllowLine or a cutText either.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin from [MackieChan: notepad-visual studio line copy](https://bitbucket.org/zastrowm/notepad-visualstudiolinecopy)

has to be still setup-ed as follow:

1. Put it into notepad++/plugin folder
2. open notepad++ (restart)
3. in Settings -> Shortcut Mapper

   under **Scintilla Commands**, remove the existing associations for Ctrl + C,X

   under **Plugin commands**, find the scripts you just created and map your shortcuts to them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for it at https://github.com/kbilsted/NppPluginCutNCopyLine its open source and the code is easy to modify if you have extra needs.

Answer (score -2):

you can write a program with a global key event hook, which every time you make a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> checks if notepad++ is the foremost application running, grabs the screen, checks if any text is selected (by looking at the screenshot and your notepad++ color settings), and sends a WM_KEYPRESS message to the notepad++ window simulating a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (assuming you're using windows).

(this won't put the line into the clipboard though, you'll have to make some character recognition to allow it)