# In notepad++: How to make it copy the line if no text is selected and the selection if text is selected?

Tags: notepad++

My java ide does this, and I have trouble living without it:

On copy action (ctrl+C):

- if text selected: copy selection
- if no selection: copy line

Anyone can help? Is there a way to write a macro with conditions?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it"? Are you looking to automate it?

Comment: Did you search for "notepad++ keyboard shortcut copy line"? First result on google contains: "Ctrl-Shft-T Copy current line to clipboard"

Comment: On copy action (ctrl+C):
- if text selected: copy selection
- if no selection: copy line

Comment: Ctrl-D duplicates the current line if that's what you're looking for, but I guess not

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about usage of a text editor.

Comment: if (selected-text) copy else copy-line

Comment: @stefan: That doesn't make it off-topic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well since the edit it actually fits better. For me, this still looks like a question such as e.g. "how to open this program in window mode". This may be done programmaticly, but to me doesn't feel right on a programming q/a site. Votes are opinion-based, that's why (except for a few trusted ones) a single person cannot perform a close.

Comment: @stefan: Notepad++ is predominantly a text editor for writing computer programming code, and questions regarding "tools primarily used for programming" are explicitly on-topic here. Yes, you are free to vote however you like, but the system works best when you get yourself informed about a thing before casting a moderation vote based on it. :)

Comment: Same question here:
Linking topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619754/how-to-mimic-visual-studios-ctrl-x-ctrl-v-functionality-in-notepad

Answer (score 1):

Found this via googling 'notepad++ copy no selection' while trying to get np++ to emulate visual studio's default copy and paste behavior.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>  duplicates the current line (as indicated in the old answers) but then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Up</kbd>  or <kbd>Down</kbd>  to move the newly duplicated line up and down to the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does the job you want.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest getting into the habit of being flexible when moving between different tools, instead of trying to shoehorn familiar features into different software. Once you've gone down that route, it's a short distance to abject disappointment.

1. Home
2. Shift+End
3. Ctrl+C

Comment: Well, it was more also to get more familiar with the capabilities of n++. 
I do know how to use a text editor ;-)